# How do I make "foreach ( string TXTname in names)" a variable without the foreach or do I need the foreach?

Tags: c#, foreach

So I am trying to store variables onto text files so my program can call on them later but I need the files to have set names and when I try that it never works correctly.

I've tried having the foreach loop in a foreach loop, I've tried so many things but all of them just screw over the variable data

```
string[] lines = { name, FirstBlock, MonIstem, WedIstem, ThridBlock, FourthBlock, "Design Time", SixthBlock, TueIstem, ThurIstem, EighthBlock, NinthBlock, "Design Time", FriIstem };
string[] names = { "name", "FirstBlock", "MonIstem", "WedIstem", "ThirdBlock", "FourthBlock", "Design Time", "SixthBlock", "TueIstem", "ThurIstem", "EightBlock", "NinthBlock", "Design Time", "FriIstem", };
foreach (string TXTname in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Saving {TXTname}");
}
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string getNameOfVar = nameof(line);
    using (FileStream bs = File.OpenWrite($@"C:\Users\gn193755\Documents\{TXTname}.txt"))
    {
        byte[] thing = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(line);
        bs.Write(thing, 0, thing.Length);
    }
}
```

No error messages but when I open the text file there is either only one text file, or they all have the same words on them, or they are just garbled text, I keep expecting there to be the correct file name with the correct text.

Comment: where are the variables in  string[] lines = {} declared? above? what type are they? are they objects? what format do you need to save them?

Comment: They are string variables

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But the code you provided can't compile because of writing errors. To help you improve the content, title and tags of your query, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* which is in the help center.

Comment: See my answer on syntax error and changing the way you write the files

Comment: The OP use TXTname out of the first loop in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so dumb, I did more research and found the .zip thing.

```
               var lines = new [] { name, FirstBlock, MonIstem, WedIstem, ThridBlock, FourthBlock, "Design Time", SixthBlock, TueIstem, ThurIstem, EighthBlock, NinthBlock, "Design Time", FriIstem };
            var names = new [] { "name", "FirstBlock", "MonIstem", "WedIstem", "ThirdBlock", "FourthBlock", "Design Time", "SixthBlock", "TueIstem", "ThurIstem", "EightBlock", "NinthBlock", "Design Time", "FriIstem", };
            var linesAndnames = lines.Zip(names, (l, n) => new { Line = l, Name = n });
            foreach (var ln  in linesAndnames)
            {
              var path = $@"C:\Users\gn193755\Documents\{ln.Name}.txt";
              File.WriteAllText(path, ln.Line);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to place, the second foreach within the first foreach.
2. If they are string variables, as an experiment use the following to create your files

```
string getNameOfVar = nameof(line);
var path = $@"C:\Users\gn193755\Documents\{TXTname}.txt");
File.WriteAllText(path, line);
```

Try this, to ensure the line strings are written correctly:

```
var path = $@"C:\Users\gn193755\Documents\output.txt");
File.AppendAllText(path, line);
```

Comment: I have tried that before and it has never worked but ill try again

Comment: This simplified the code a lot and the problem was not as bad as before but it still has issues, ill keep tinkering with this

Comment: Here is what I came up with

Comment: foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    foreach (string TXTname in names)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Saving {TXTname}");
                        var path = $@"C:\Users\gn193755\Documents\{TXTname}.txt";
                        File.WriteAllText(path, line);
                    }

                }

Comment: Replace ```File.WriteAllText(path, line);``` with ```File.AppendAllText(path, line);``` and just hard code the name of file to ```output.txt```

Answer (score 0):

As seen into the code the foreach loops are seperate.

```
string[] lines = { name, FirstBlock, MonIstem, WedIstem, ThridBlock, FourthBlock, "Design Time", SixthBlock, TueIstem, ThurIstem, EighthBlock, NinthBlock, "Design Time", FriIstem };
string[] names = { "name", "FirstBlock", "MonIstem", "WedIstem", "ThirdBlock", "FourthBlock", "Design Time", "SixthBlock", "TueIstem", "ThurIstem", "EightBlock", "NinthBlock", "Design Time", "FriIstem", };
        foreach (string TXTname in names)
        {
                Console.WriteLine($"Saving {TXTname}");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {

                string getNameOfVar = nameof(line);
                using (FileStream bs = File.OpenWrite($@"C:\Users\gn193755\Documents\{TXTname}.txt"))
                {
                    byte[] thing = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(line);
                    bs.Write(thing, 0, thing.Length);
                }
            }
        }
```

Try using the above code

Comment: I encounter the same problem I have been encountering all the time, they all have the same data on them.